# Combine find and jar -xvf?

Tags: unix, command-line, find

We [know](https://superuser.com/questions/513304/how-to-combine-tar-command-with-find) how to combine `find` and `tar cvf`.

How to combine each file using `-exec` on `find` with a command like `jar -xvf`?

The use case is, I need to find specific jar files (e.g. `-type f foo*.jar`) in a folder and then extract specific entries from each jar file that `find` finds: `jar -xvf <file> META-INF/services`

The general case seems to be that the user wants to `exec` a command `cmd` for each file that is found when `cmd` takes argument(s) *after* the file.

Comment: Is `foreach` a better idea here: (`for f in *.jar; do jar xvf $f META-INF/services; done`)?

Comment: Or, (`for f in $(find . -name *.jar); do jar xvf $f META-INF/services; done`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find -exec` lets you substitute a file name anywhere in the command. As in the linked question, you can do this with by moving `{}` to the desired location.

```
find /path -name '*.jar' -exec jar -xvf {} META-INF/services \;
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that `{}` acts like a placeholder! Thanks.